# how can I get this readdir code sample to search other directories

Tags: c, file-io, glob

I am currently working with a code example that initially is designed to take an argument, then search for that argument in the current directory, I've tried to make it search another directory (/dev/shm to exact) by replacing the "." with "/dev/shm" but the code turns up nothing when i search for something* (notice the wildcard). The wild card search works fine in the current directory so I do not think it is the wild card that is the problem, If someone could help me out though I would really appreciate it, thanks!

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


static void lookup(const char *arg)
{
    DIR *dirp;
    struct dirent *dp;


    if ((dirp = opendir(".")) == NULL) {
        perror("couldn't open '.'");
        return;
    }


    do {
        errno = 0;
        if ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(dp->d_name, arg) != 0)
                continue;


            (void) printf("found %s\n", arg);
            (void) closedir(dirp);
                return;


        }
    } while (dp != NULL);


    if (errno != 0)
        perror("error reading directory");
    else
        (void) printf("failed to find %s\n", arg);
    (void) closedir(dirp);
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        lookup(argv[i]);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: you don't have to write `(void)` in front of function calls.

Comment: @Eitan - (void) is there to get past older versions of lint.  The OP posted an example from the the readdir man page. And.  Good code should check the return code from every call, even printf.

Comment: @jimmcnamara I believe that with or without `(void)` the compiler essentially does the same thing. By putting `(void)` you're merely making it more obvious that you're discarding the return value. I actually never saw this "style" before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`opendir` doesn't handle wildcards.  It expects a real directory path.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say

> wildcard search works in the current directory

If you mean it works in your shell, that's to be expected.  The shell will first expand the wildcard and then perform the command you typed.

So how to solve this?  Expand the wildcard yourself using `glob` before calling `opendir`.

---

Edit: sorry, I thought you were trying to match the wildcard in the directory name.  It looks like you want to match directory contents using the wildcard.  In that case simply replace

```
if (strcmp(dp->d_name, arg) != 0)
```

with

```
if (fnmatch(arg, dp->d_name, 0) != 0)
```

---

You could also use `glob` for this.  It will actually replace the call to `opendir` and the loop.  Here is an example for using `glob`:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static void lookup(const char *root, const char *arg)
{
    size_t n;
    glob_t res;
    char **p;

    chdir(root);
    glob(arg, 0, 0, &res);

    n = res.gl_pathc;
    if (n < 1) {
        printf("failed to find %s\n", arg);
    } else {
        for (p = res.gl_pathv; n; p++, n--) {
            printf("found %s\n", *p);
        }
    }
    globfree(&res);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++)
        lookup(argv[1], argv[i]);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice :) i've looked around for some examples/tutorials on using glob, but am having a difficult time actually finding out what is going on in most of them, so i was wondering if you knew how to use glob by any chance?

Comment: thanks again, one question though, with fnmatch part, when I use that, it will only show that the file was found, say for instance the directory contains 1-a.txt 1-b.txt 1-c.txt and I searched for 1-*.txt, the program would just return 1-*.txt was found instead of 1-a.txt 1-b.txt 1-c.txt were found, although Im not sure if I may just be missing something

Comment: First, there has to be a wildcard in the pattern, but I think that's just a copy-paste problem :)  Check the logic in your loop.  If there is no match (`fnmatch` or `strcmp` return non-zero) you go to the next element in the directory.  If there is a match you print it and exit.  Move the exit part out of the loop and you are all set.

Comment: neat :) so would I be removing the return; under close dir?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are expecting. If your program is called `lookup` then if you call it in the 'current directory', where that directory holds files something.1, something.2 and something.3 like this:

```
lookup something*
```

the shell will expand it to

```
lookup  something.1 something.2 something.3
```

and your program will see three command line args and will be able to find a match in the readdir loop.

If you change the opendir call to "/dev/shm" and call it from the original directory (the one that has something.[1-3]) then the shell will again expand the wildcard `in the current directory`.  But unless the files  something.1, something.2 and something.3 are also present in /dev/shm, the readdir loop will not see them.

Note that your lookup function is a bit odd.  I would expect it to be more like this:

```
    static int lookup(const char * dir, const char *arg)
    {
        DIR *dirp;
        struct dirent *dp;

        if ((dirp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
            perror(dir);
            return -1;
        }

        while ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
            if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, arg)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        (void) closedir(dirp);

        printf("%s %s\n", dp ? "found" : "failed to find", arg);
        return 0;
    }
```