# How can I search for files in a directory using a wildcard

Tags: c, file-io

I am currently trying to find a way to search for files in a specific directory (/dev/shm in this instance, no wild card needed for this part) that fit a pattern that includes a wild card, lets say for instance I have a directory that has

```
stack_review.txt stack_overflow.txt stack_servers.txt
```

in it, and I wanted to return all results that fit the pattern stack_*.txt, how would I got about doing this? Ive tried a few examples using readdir but unfortunately have not found anything that works correctly for this implementation yet, So I would really appreciate any help that I can get with this problem, thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to use shell globbing patterns or regex ("grep") patterns?  There is a difference.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob ? Or do you want cross-platform (I don't think so from the post).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10678765/643500

Comment: an yes I would be using shell globbing patterns, this would be run on a debian squeeze build

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I get this readdir code sample to search other directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678522/how-can-i-get-this-readdir-code-sample-to-search-other-directories)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `glob()`. From http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob:

One example of use is the following code, which simulates typing `ls -l *.c ../*.c`
in the shell:

```
glob_t globbuf;

globbuf.gl_offs = 2;
glob("*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);
glob("../*.c", GLOB_DOOFFS | GLOB_APPEND, NULL, &globbuf);
globbuf.gl_pathv[0] = "ls";
globbuf.gl_pathv[1] = "-l";
execvp("ls", &globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);
```

Comment: +1, but do keep in mind that `glob` isn't standard C and so isn't available on all platforms (notably Windows).  It is POSIX, though, so it's pretty commonly available.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for elements to be nested in folders? If so your method must be recursive.